How to load local image files to a hugging faces dataset?
I am trying to load_dataset of huggingfaces from local directory. I tried:
os.system('mkdir mydataset')
os.system('mkdir mydataset/train')
os.system('mkdir mydataset/train/dog/')
os.system('mkdir mydataset/train/cat/')
im1 = np.arange(20*20*3, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((20,20,3))
plt.imsave('mydataset/train/dog/im1.jpg', im1)
im2 = np.arange(20*20*3, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((20,20,3))
plt.imsave('mydataset/train/dog/im2.jpg', im2)
im3 = np.arange(20*20*3, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((20,20,3))
plt.imsave('mydataset/train/cat/im3.jpg', im3)
im4 = np.arange(20*20*3, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((20,20,3))
plt.imsave('mydataset/train/cat/im4.jpg', im4)
train_dataset = load_dataset("imagefolder", "mydataset")

I get the same error, for any variation I tried as: load_dataset("mydataset") or load_dataset("imagefolder", "mydataset", split='train).
What am i doing wrong ?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[55], line 1
----> 1 ds=load_dataset("imagefolder", data_dir="/home/labs/olenderlab/naomifr/segmentation/spy2/train/", split="train")

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/load.py:2523, in load_dataset(path, name, data_dir, data_files, split, cache_dir, features, download_config, download_mode, verification_mode, ignore_verifications, keep_in_memory, save_infos, revision, token, use_auth_token, task, streaming, num_proc, storage_options, trust_remote_code, **config_kwargs)
   2518 verification_mode = VerificationMode(
   2519     (verification_mode or VerificationMode.BASIC_CHECKS) if not save_infos else VerificationMode.ALL_CHECKS
   2520 )
   2522 # Create a dataset builder
-> 2523 builder_instance = load_dataset_builder(
   2524     path=path,
   2525     name=name,
   2526     data_dir=data_dir,
   2527     data_files=data_files,
   2528     cache_dir=cache_dir,
   2529     features=features,
   2530     download_config=download_config,
   2531     download_mode=download_mode,
   2532     revision=revision,
   2533     token=token,
   2534     storage_options=storage_options,
   2535     trust_remote_code=trust_remote_code,
   2536     _require_default_config_name=name is None,
   2537     **config_kwargs,
   2538 )
   2540 # Return iterable dataset in case of streaming
   2541 if streaming:

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/load.py:2195, in load_dataset_builder(path, name, data_dir, data_files, cache_dir, features, download_config, download_mode, revision, token, use_auth_token, storage_options, trust_remote_code, _require_default_config_name, **config_kwargs)
   2193     download_config = download_config.copy() if download_config else DownloadConfig()
   2194     download_config.storage_options.update(storage_options)
-> 2195 dataset_module = dataset_module_factory(
   2196     path,
   2197     revision=revision,
   2198     download_config=download_config,
   2199     download_mode=download_mode,
   2200     data_dir=data_dir,
   2201     data_files=data_files,
   2202     cache_dir=cache_dir,
   2203     trust_remote_code=trust_remote_code,
   2204     _require_default_config_name=_require_default_config_name,
   2205     _require_custom_configs=bool(config_kwargs),
   2206 )
   2207 # Get dataset builder class from the processing script
   2208 builder_kwargs = dataset_module.builder_kwargs

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/load.py:1730, in dataset_module_factory(path, revision, download_config, download_mode, dynamic_modules_path, data_dir, data_files, cache_dir, trust_remote_code, _require_default_config_name, _require_custom_configs, **download_kwargs)
   1713 # We have several ways to get a dataset builder:
   1714 #
   1715 # - if path is the name of a packaged dataset module
   (...)
   1727 
   1728 # Try packaged
   1729 if path in _PACKAGED_DATASETS_MODULES:
-> 1730     return PackagedDatasetModuleFactory(
   1731         path,
   1732         data_dir=data_dir,
   1733         data_files=data_files,
   1734         download_config=download_config,
   1735         download_mode=download_mode,
   1736     ).get_module()
   1737 # Try locally
   1738 elif path.endswith(filename):

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/load.py:1119, in PackagedDatasetModuleFactory.get_module(self)
   1117 def get_module(self) -> DatasetModule:
   1118     base_path = Path(self.data_dir or "").expanduser().resolve().as_posix()
-> 1119     patterns = sanitize_patterns(self.data_files) if self.data_files is not None else get_data_patterns(base_path)
   1120     data_files = DataFilesDict.from_patterns(
   1121         patterns,
   1122         download_config=self.download_config,
   1123         base_path=base_path,
   1124     )
   1125     supports_metadata = self.name in _MODULE_SUPPORTS_METADATA

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/data_files.py:473, in get_data_patterns(base_path, download_config)
    471 resolver = partial(resolve_pattern, base_path=base_path, download_config=download_config)
    472 try:
--> 473     return _get_data_files_patterns(resolver)
    474 except FileNotFoundError:
    475     raise EmptyDatasetError(f"The directory at {base_path} doesn't contain any data files") from None

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/data_files.py:260, in _get_data_files_patterns(pattern_resolver)
    258 for pattern in patterns:
    259     try:
--> 260         data_files = pattern_resolver(pattern)
    261     except FileNotFoundError:
    262         continue

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/datasets/data_files.py:344, in resolve_pattern(pattern, base_path, allowed_extensions, download_config)
    342     base_path = ""
    343 pattern, storage_options = _prepare_path_and_storage_options(pattern, download_config=download_config)
--> 344 fs, _, _ = get_fs_token_paths(pattern, storage_options=storage_options)
    345 fs_base_path = base_path.split("::")[0].split("://")[-1] or fs.root_marker
    346 fs_pattern = pattern.split("::")[0].split("://")[-1]

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/core.py:653, in get_fs_token_paths(urlpath, mode, num, name_function, storage_options, protocol, expand)
    651     paths = _expand_paths(paths, name_function, num)
    652 elif "*" in paths:
--> 653     paths = [f for f in sorted(fs.glob(paths)) if not fs.isdir(f)]
    654 else:
    655     paths = [paths]

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/spec.py:606, in AbstractFileSystem.glob(self, path, maxdepth, **kwargs)
    602         depth = None
    604 allpaths = self.find(root, maxdepth=depth, withdirs=True, detail=True, **kwargs)
--> 606 pattern = glob_translate(path + ("/" if ends_with_sep else ""))
    607 pattern = re.compile(pattern)
    609 out = {
    610     p: info
    611     for p, info in sorted(allpaths.items())
   (...)
    618     )
    619 }

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pytr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fsspec/utils.py:734, in glob_translate(pat)
    732     continue
    733 elif "**" in part:
--> 734     raise ValueError(
    735         "Invalid pattern: '**' can only be an entire path component"
    736     )
    737 if part:
    738     results.extend(_translate(part, f"{not_sep}*", not_sep))

ValueError: Invalid pattern: '**' can only be an entire path component

